# create multiple projects error Azure DevOps rest api

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using a rest API powershell to create multiple projects in azure devops. Writing my script in below way but it fails.
Any guidance on how I can construct my script to pick up multiple names?

```
'
    $connectionToken="token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$ProjectUrl = "url 
$Body = @{
        name = @{'TestProjectCreation1','test1','test2'

}
        description = 'Frabrikam travel app for Windows Phone'
        capabilities = @{
          versioncontrol = @{
            sourceControlType = 'Git'
          }
          processTemplate = @{
            templateTypeId = 'template id'
          }
        }
      } | ConvertTo-Json
$projectscreated = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ProjectUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"  -Headers @{
    Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $Body

'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you could create a new array for projects and foreach the project to create: scrpit like:

```
$url='https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0'
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$projects= @('TestProjectCreation1','test1','test2')
Foreach($prject in $projects){

$body="
  {
    `"name`": `"$prject`",
    `"capabilities`": {
      `"versioncontrol`": {
      `"sourceControlType`": `"Git`"
    },
    `"processTemplate`": {
      `"templateTypeId`": `"6b724908-ef14-45cf-84f8-768b5384da45`"
    }
  }
  }
"
$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
}
```

Comment: hello Ging, I tried below way but still erroring me out                              
     foreach($project in $projects){
        $Body = @{
        name = $project
           } | ConvertTo-Json
$projectscreated = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ProjectUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"  -Headers @{
    Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $Body

Comment: Hi Priya, I have changed my answer, please just change the {org} and {PAT} to check if it works. If not, please share the detailed error message.

Comment: Not related to the same api, but when I try to send GET request in postman to get the user details in an org, it gives me page not found error even when the PAT seems okay. let me know if i am missing anything.
 https://dev.azure.com/orgname/_apis/userentitlements?top=100&skip=0&api-version=4.1-preview.1

Comment: https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview.1

maybe missed "vsaex"